# Display Data from database other table to Prestashop 1.7.7.6 Product Page WITHOUT module in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Display Data from database other table to Prestashop Product Page - Prestashop 1.7.7.6 WITHOUT module in PHP

Hello everyone

How can i display data from other table database in Prestashop Product Page - Prestashop 1.7.7.6 WITHOUT module

I want to select data in table of database and display in front office prestashop product page tpl file

How can i do ?

please help me

Thanks You very much in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in prestashop product page, select data in database and display result in product page detail , how can i do this ? thanks

Comment: override the product controller, write your sql query & pass the data to tpl via smarty assign method, please mention your PS version, then i can tell you the exact methods that you need to override

Comment: thanks @AbdullaChozhimadathil, my prestashop version 1.7.7.6 so impossible to override product controller, please give me a example ?

Comment: @mass12 were you able to do this with override?

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the Prestashop hooks:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/

The best way is to create(generate) a new module in the PrestaShop validator website:
https://validator.prestashop.com/generator
and use the `displayProductAdditionalInfo()` hook.

Without PHP you can't do this.